# Emacs shortcuts in term mode

Tags: emacs

I've a question about using Emacs as editor and terminal.

I split my window into different windows with `C-x 3`for example. One of the generated Window is used as terminal with `M-x term`. Usually I switch with `C-x o`into another window. Suppose I switched to the terminal buffer, from there I cannot use `C-x o` to switch to another buffer.

What short cut can I use to switch from the terminal buffer into another?

Comment: Do you know about M-x shell? It plays nicer with emacs.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It seems that there `C-c o` is working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> `C-c CHAR`
>        This is equivalent to `C-x CHAR` in normal Emacs.  For example,
>        `C-c o` invokes the global binding of `C-x o`, which is normally
>        `other-window`.

(Emacs info file, "Term mode")

Comment: Perhabs my question was not clear. In every window, I can switch to antoher using the short cut `C-x o`. In the terminal window, nothing happens. I have to use the mouse to switch to another window. This just does not work in the terminal window! So, my question, is there another short cut to switch from a terminal window in Emacs to another?

Comment: If I use `C-c CHAR`, in my case, `C-c o` nothing happens in Emacs.

Comment: Are you using normal `term-mode`?  `C-c o` works for me, after `M-x term RET RET` (which prompts for `/bin/bash` in my case but that should not affect things).  Also, what version of Emacs?  (Mine is 23.4.1)

Comment: Im using 23.4.1, too. Yes, I did exactly the same `M-x term RET RET`. Strange, .... I just note that I can't kill the window running terminal with `C-x k`. It seems that in such a terminal window I'm not able to use short cuts.

Comment: The standard `emacs` commands are not available in terminal windows, because you often need to be able to send keys directly to what's running in the window; that's why `C-c` is normally rebound.  I don't know why that isn't working for you.

Answer (score 2):

C-c C-j switches to line mode, when you need to do Emacs-y things to the buffer    (Term: line run) appears in status line

C-c C-k switches back to char mode, when you need it to act like a terminal again  (Term: char run) appears in status line